# Find the prob. to win third prize in lottery game

Tags: probability, permutations

I have a question about prob. The question is "A lottery game that chooses 5 numbers out of 50 numbers. What is probability to win the third prize which is the case matching 3 out of the 5 numbers " 
Thanks in advance

This is what I done: We selected $5$ numbers from $50$ numbers, so, the total case is
$\binom{50}{5}$

The possible case that matches $3$ number out of $5$ number is $5 \times 45 \times 45$

Hence, prob. to win third prize is
$$\frac{5 \times 45 \times 45}{\binom{50}{5}}$$

Is it correct? It it wrong, Coud you help me solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To win third prize, you need to get two wrong numbers.  There are ${45\choose 2}$ ways to pick two (unordered) wrong numbers.  You also need to get three right numbers.  There are ${5\choose 3}$ ways to get three right numbers.  Hence the answer you seek is $$\frac{{45\choose 2}{5\choose 3}}{{50\choose 5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The total ways in which one could choose 5 numbers out of 50 numbers is $50!/45!$. If the order of the numbers doesn't matter, it's $50!/45!5!$. Likewise, the amount of ways one could choose three numbers out of fifty is $50!/47!3!$ So the probability of choose three matching numbers is$\frac{50!/47!3!}{50!/45!5!)}$. This simplifies down to $10/1081$